# Project dependency for git cloners

Tags: c++, git, bash

I have a project on GitHub which is dependant on another project (which has its own git repository). Both projects use CMake for compilation.

The project mine is depending on, when compiled, has:

- two `include/` folders (one directly shipped by the git repo, one generated by CMake) containing the headers;
- a `lib/` folder containing compiled binary libraries that my project will be linked against;
- a `bin/` folder containing utility tools.

I want that when someone clones my git repository, that project will be downloaded and compiled, and those folders will be copied in an accessible folder I can reference from my project.

Is there a good way to achieve this? Maybe the download of that project can't be automatic but my goal is to make the new cloner do as little work as possible to set up the environment.

**EDIT:** I know about submodules but I read that they can be replaced by other dependency managers that offer more features. But my question was if there’s a way to make git call a bash script or something like that after the cloning.

Answer (score 1):

Until now I found those ones:

- https://github.com/bpkg/bpkg
- https://github.com/basherpm/basher

But only bpkg seems to handle project dependencies for now so I guess it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The way to do what you are describing is called "Submodules".  You can read about them in the [Git SCM book - Chap 7.11 Git Tools - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

The short version - submodules allow you to essentially have a clone of another git repo in a subfolder in your original repo.  You can set things up so that a fetch recursively fetches all submodules, or you can make the updates to submodules manual.

I've not used them yet, but I have seen plenty of warnings that they can be tricky - that being said, they were designed to handle this use case specifically.

Comment: I know about submodules but I read that they can be replaced by other dependency managers that offer more features. But my question was if there’s a way to make git call a bash script or something like that after the cloning.